# convert string array to normal array in php

Tags: php

I have a response from a API which is array in a string, i want to format in normal array, any help appreciable.

> '[{"CODCHARGE":30.000,"DockNo":"I31000106219","OrderNo":"47735530","Reason":"Order
>   Nos uploaded Successfully!!","Succeed":"Yes","TotalFreight":125.000}]'

i want to remove first and last single qoutes from array.

```
format should be :- 
 [
   {"CODCHARGE":30.000,
    "DockNo":"I31000106219",
    "OrderNo":"47735530",
   "Reason":"Order Nos uploaded Successfully!!",
   "Succeed":"Yes","TotalFreight":125.000
  }
]
```

Comment: use `json_decode` function

Comment: that's not a "string array" - such a thing doesn't even exist. that's `JSON`. which the API documentation would most probably have told you. just use `json_decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), and if you want convert to an array, secondary argument must be `true` or `1`.

```
$string = '[{"CODCHARGE":30.000,"DockNo":"I31000106219","OrderNo":"47735530","Reason":"Order Nos uploaded Successfully!!","Succeed":"Yes","TotalFreight":125.000}]';
$array = json_decode( $string, true );
print_r($array);
```

After convert:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CODCHARGE] => 30
            [DockNo] => I31000106219
            [OrderNo] => 47735530
            [Reason] => Order Nos uploaded Successfully!!
            [Succeed] => Yes
            [TotalFreight] => 125
        )

)
```